# Relation between $(\mathcal H \cap \mathcal G)^*$ and $\mathcal H ^* \cap \mathcal G ^*$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal G$ be affine hypersurfaces and let $\mathcal H ^*$ and $\mathcal G ^*$ be their projective closures. Is there a relation between $(\mathcal H \cap \mathcal G)^*$ and $\mathcal H ^* \cap \mathcal G ^*$?

I tried to find a relation with concrete examples, but it is the first time I work with projective closures and I didn't get to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have always $\overline{(H \cap G)} \subset \overline{H} \cap \overline{G}$. Indeed, $H \cap G \subset H$ so $\overline{H \cap G} \subset \overline{H}$ and similarly for $G$, so  $\overline{(H \cap G)} \subset \overline{H} \cap \overline{G}$.

You can't expect equality in general : for example if $H,G$ are two parallel lines in $\Bbb A^2$, then $\overline{H \cap G}$ is empty and $\overline{H} \cap \overline{G}$ is a point.